# What type of notices and licenses do I need to add when adding (and modifying) code from an Apache 2.0 codebase to my own MIT codebase?

Tags: mit, apache-2.0

I want to add code from an Apache 2.0 software to my own code base which is MIT. I know that generally these are compatible but my worry is how to add the Apache 2.0 code with the appropriate modifications, remarks, new files and licenses.

My plan was to simply make a new folder with the Apache code in my own code copy their license and code (and my modifications there).

Do I need to do anything else? Where does the `notices.md` file go and what do I add to it?

I also need to include a copyright. Where does that go? Where do stating the changes to the software go?

---

This page https://tldrlegal.com/license/apache-license-2.0-(apache-2.0) recommends:

- Must
- Include Copyright

  Describes whether the original copyright must be retained.
- Include License

  Including the full text of license in modified software.
- State Changes

  Stating significant changes made to software.
- Include Notice

  If the library has a "NOTICE" file with attribution notes, you must include that NOTICE when you distribute. You may append to this NOTICE file.

---

References from my research:

- https://www.quora.com/Is-the-MIT-license-compatible-with-the-Apache-License-Version-2-APLv2
- https://www.quora.com/Can-I-use-Apache-licensed-source-code-and-redistribute-it-as-MIT-license
- [Can I copy code licensed under Apache 2 to a project licensed under MIT?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/4102/can-i-copy-code-licensed-under-apache-2-to-a-project-licensed-under-mit?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [What happens when a MIT licensed project uses Apache 2.0 drivers to connect to GPLv3 databases?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/9262/what-happens-when-a-mit-licensed-project-uses-apache-2-0-drivers-to-connect-to-g)

Answer (score 4):

You can use (and modify) the codebase of the Apache component under the Apache license. You cannot re-license the Apache code to use MIT in the future, because there are addnl restrictions in the Apache license (stating changes, trademark use) which do not appear in the MIT license.

I always recommend to have one file licenses.md (or .txt or whatever) either in the top folder or in a 'licenses' subfolder, and include everything in that one file. In addition you should put a 'notices.md' into the same folder with the copyright attribution, list of changes etc. Some people put the notices in the same file with the licenses, but I think that makes it very difficult to read.

Comment: so is having the apache code on it's own place with it's own license separate from the top of my code (which is MIT) - ok? Do I need to add any comments at the top of my code that some subfolders are Apache?

Comment: @CharlieParker Keeping the Apache licensed code in a separate subfolder is certainly good practice. You should clarify the different licenses of the different components in one license.md file for your project. You may want to consider adding SPDX declarations in each of the files.