# How can I use Apache License-2.0-licensed software in my MIT-licensed software?

Tags: apache-2.0, license-notice, license

> • License and copyright notice

May I add notice to LICENSE file like the following?

```
MIT License

Copyright (c) 2021 me

Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to...

-----

                              Apache License
                        Version 2.0, January 200...
```

> • State changes

My software is not fork of it, so I will not do anything related to this, isn't it?

Comment: Have you used Search and checked if your question has already been answered here? Is [this](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/12263/what-type-of-notices-and-licenses-do-i-need-to-add-when-adding-and-modifying-c?rq=1) answering your question?